# update Jenkins from 1.424 to 1.426,it don't work

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins:http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog
What's new in 1.426 (2011/08/15)

1. Auto Install JDK asks for Oracle account, but the link goes 404.
   (issue 10556)
2. Record and display who aborted builds.
3. Added API token support. (issue 9363)
4. Maven Plugin can use settings and global settings files provided by
   the config provider plugin Fixed background of title image (issue
   9571)
   when i run mvn project,failed.

13:10:22  Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
13:10:23  channel stopped
13:10:25  FATAL: null
13:10:27  java.lang.NullPointerException
13:10:27    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:833)
13:10:27    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:448)
13:10:27    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1376)
13:10:27    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:479)
13:10:27    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
13:10:27    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)

i rollback 1.424,it work.

Comment: We have a similar issue related to NPE.

Comment: We ran into a the EXACT same problem (on a windows server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened in our environment after upgrading to 1.426. (Windows running a multi-slave-setup).

The issue is now registered in the Jenkins issue tracker:

- [JENKINS-10715
  Finishing with a Null Pointer Exception after a successful build.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10715), and the duplicate
- [JENKINS-10755
  NPE after successful project build with maven](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10755)